# Searching String for a Unicode Character

Tags: python, unicode

I'm sorry if this has already been posted here, but I wasn't sure what to search. I'm using Python and I want to find a  character in a string of text. The string looks like this: ☺G18M1329D3920,2511171♥7006. I'm interested in that heart. I know it's a binary 6 but how would I return it's position using a string method similar to .find()?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "binary 6" and "binary character"?

Comment: `u"☺G18M1329D3920,2511171♥7006".encode("utf8").index("\xe2\x99\xa5")
.index('♥')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "binary" I think you mean "Unicode code point". That is the numerical representation of a character.

Unicode code points can be represented in a python string literal by escaping the code point in your string.
The 'heart' symbol is actually code point U+2665.

So you can write your string like this:

```
mystring = u'\u263aG18M1329D3920,2511171\u26657006'
```

Notice that I escaped the 'heart' by using \u followed by the code point 2665.

Armed with this knowledge, you can apply it to `find()`

```
mystring.find(u'\u2665')
```

**edit:** Python 2.7 requires the `u` prefix before the string literal.

Comment: If you are using Python 2.x, only `unicode` literals recognize the `\u` escape: `u'\u2665'`. `'\u2665'` is simply a 6-character string consisting of a backslash, the letter 'u', and 4 numerical digits.